# How to pass multiple array of struct to a single function in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct, binary

I have 2 different array of structs (user and guest) and I'd like to know how pass them to a single function. For example I have these structs

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} date;

typedef struct {
    short id;
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    char *email;
    char *password;
    date birthday;
} user;

typedef struct {
    short id;
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    char *email;
} guest;
```

and I want to save the data in a binary file using the same function. But despite I tried to inform myself how to pass multiple structs to a single function, I'm having problem on *how to pass **multiple array of structs** to a single function*. Here's what I tried to achieve so far. The file is generated but it's incomplete. The writing procedure stops at a specific data for both of the structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_USER 20
#define MAX_GUEST 20

user record_user[MAX_USER] = {
{ 1     , "Name 1"          , "Surname 1"           , "name1.surname1@email.com"            , "S\\(6`].}"   ,{ 9    , 3     , 1994 }    ,{ 10   , 3     , 2010 } },
{ 2     , "Name 2"          , "Surname 2"           , "name2.surname2@email.com"            , "O!5[0R9P"    ,{ 29   , 8     , 1977 }    ,{ 18   , 1     , 2009 } },
{ 3     , "Name 3"          , "Surname 3"           , "name3.surname3@email.com"            , "j+$\"XrLw"   ,{ 15   , 9     , 1971 }    ,{ 14   , 3     , 2013 } },
{ 4     , "Name 4"          , "Surname 4"           , "name4.surname4@email.com"            , "\"n^{:&}("   ,{ 15   , 7     , 1980 }    ,{ 11   , 6     , 2011 } },
{ 5     , "Name 5"          , "Surname 5"           , "name5.surname5@email.com"            , "JHKv%Kgg"    ,{ 15   , 4     , 1975 }    ,{ 19   , 8     , 2011 } },
{ 6     , "Name 6"          , "Surname 6"           , "name6.surname6@email.com"            , "o_bsggpN"    ,{ 28   , 5     , 1989 }    ,{ 18   , 9     , 2009 } },
/* it keeps going */
};

guest record_guest[MAX_GUEST] = {
{ 1     , "Name 1"          , "Surname 1"           , "name1.surname1@email.com" },
{ 2     , "Name 2"          , "Surname 2"           , "name2.surname2@email.com" },
{ 3     , "Name 3"          , "Surname 3"           , "name3.surname3@email.com" },
{ 4     , "Name 4"          , "Surname 4"           , "name4.surname4@email.com" },
{ 5     , "Name 5"          , "Surname 5"           , "name5.surname5@email.com" },
{ 6     , "Name 6"          , "Surname 6"           , "name6.surname6@email.com" },
/* it keeps going */
};


    int main() {
        /* some prev code */
        save(record_user, "user.dat", MAX_USER);
        /* some middle code */
        save(record_guest, "guest.dat", MAX_GUEST);
        /* some after code */
        return 0;
    }

    void save(void *data[], char *filename, int size) {
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen(filename, "rb+");

        // If the file is missing, it is created
        if (file == NULL) {
            file = fopen(filename, "wb");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            fwrite(&data[i], sizeof(data[i]), 1, file);
        }

        fclose(file);
    };
```

Comment: Wont work: `sizeof(data[i]),`  will be `sizeof(void *),` , which is constant , and doesn't depend on the actual array.Also, it makes no sense to write pointer values to disk, they have no meaning outside your running program.

Comment: You should add an enumeration to your `save` function to distinguish a `user` from a `guest`. Like: `void save(void *data, char *filename, int size, int user_type);`. And then cast the `data` pointer with the correct structure.

Comment: Well I need to rework on that. You have to know the size of any fields of your structure in order to have a consistent `sizeof`

Comment: regarding: `fwrite(&data[i], sizeof(data[i]), 1, file);`  the only 'size' that the compiler knows is the size of a pointer (say 4 or 8 bytes)  The compiler knows NOTHING about the size of the target of a `void*`

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question: *I have 2 different array of structs (user and guest) and I'd like to know how pass them to a single function.*: Combine them while including a `union` and an `enum` in that combined definition...

A few related architectural suggestions:

- 1st, eliminate the pointer members in your structs and replace them
  with 'large enough' arrays. (This will greatly simplify the memory allocations and corresponding calls to `free()` ).
- 2nd, create a single combined struct, eg. VISITORS, containing all
  the others.
- 3rd, use an `enum` to distinguish between type of record to
  create/store/use the data etc.
- 4th, use a union to contain 2 types of visitors.

In this way, you can pass a single `struct` argument in your functions.

```
#define MAX_VISITOR 20

typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} date;

typedef enum {
    USER,
    GUEST
} TYPE;

typedef struct {
    short id;
    char name[30];  //no pointers here, just create 'large enough' arrays
    char surname[30];  
    char email[30];
    char password[30];
    date birthday;
} user;

typedef struct {
    short id;        
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    char email[30];
} guest;

typedef struct {
    date d;       //date
    TYPE t;       //either USER or GUEST
    union   {     //(only one member will be populated per instance of VISITOR)
        user u;   //6 elements
        guest g;  //4 elements 
    };
} VISITOR;

void StoreVisitors(VISITOR *v); //these prototypes will accept a single argument containing single struct. 
void UpdateVisitors(VISITORS **v);

int main(void)
{
    VISITOR *pV = calloc(MAX_VISITOR, sizeof(*pV)); //20 instances of VISITOR
    if(pV)
    {
        UpdateVisitors(&pV);
        StoreVisitors(pV);
    }
    free(pV);


    return 0;
}

void StoreVisitors(VISITOR *p)
{
    // Write the information in p to the data file      
}

void UpdateVisitors(VISITOR **v)
{
    // Read records from existing visitor files
    // and update array of struct VISITOR with data     
}
```

Comment: If you have to use legacy C and can't use _Generic, then the union version is the second best option. There's the "common initial sequence rule", found in a dark, forgotten corner of the C standard (6.5.2.3/6), which allows us to do things like `user u; ... guest* gptr = (guest*)&u; /* use gptr */`, which is actually well-defined and portable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `sizeof(data[i])` which is nonsense, it gives you a void pointer size.

With modern standard C programming (C11) you can do like this:

```
void guest_save (size_t size, guest array[size], const char* filename);

void user_save (size_t size, user array[size], const char* filename);

#define save(size, array, filename) \
  _Generic((array),                 \
           guest*: guest_save,      \
           user*:  user_save)(size, array, filename)
```

With this method you won't have to use dangerous void pointers. And you can now easily take `sizeof array[i]` etc.

Comment: @Lundin am i wrong or in this way you have to declare and write twice the function (guest_save & user_save)? I was trying to avoid that, finding something more clean and elegant... but thanks anyway

Comment: @JohnnyKing94 Not really, you could let those two functions be wrappers around the file I/O. Something along the lines of `void guest_save (size_t size, guest array[size], const char* filename) { file_write (filename, array, size, sizeof(guest); ...` where `file_write` doesn't concern itself with the types used, only their sizes. With that design you separate the struct type-specific behavior from file I/O.